# How to use and search multiple checklist facets with one button

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I have a search page using 2 checklist facets, Size and Color. How can I make it so that I can use one button to apply the search for options checked in both facets? E.g. I check 'large' in the Size facet and 'blue' in the Color facet and I click one button to apply both searches?

Currently the 'apply filter' buttons for both facets are hidden, and I have an external button, that when clicked, will 'click' both of the hidden apply filter buttons with JS. I have a similar setup for the clear filter button, which works, but when I click my external apply button, only the options from the first facet (Size) are applied.

If after this search, I click on an option in the second (Color) facet, and click the external apply button, it will append my Color option to my first 'large' Size search. But I want to be able to apply both filters at the same time.

I have confirmed that clicking my external button is clicking the real 'apply filter' button on both facets. Is there anything else I can try to make this work?

Thanks.